# How to display the archive for native posts

Tags: archives

I want to display an index of all posts, separate from the homepage.

The current settings on my WordPress Admin > Reading is:

[image]

I have a file called archive.php in my theme folder.

But when I visit the page "Blog", it's loading the index.php file. Not page.php and not archive.php.

How can I make it load the archive.php template file?

The official docs (https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) don't say anything about it, maybe I'm looking at the wrong docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs you’re looking for are: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ You need to use `home.php` or `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks. In any case, I ended up creating a CPT for this. It makes more sense like that.

Comment: In what way does it make more sense? It’s a bit of a red flag to be honest.

Comment: It makes more sense because I can just create a template called archive-articles.php which is more in line with the other structures on the site (archive-events.php, ...) and also, I was renaming the "Post" label to "Article" anyways. In what sense is it a red flag? Thanks again for helping.